# highchart/highstock tooltip does not adjust after zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using highstocks to plot a serie. When using tooltip pointformat showing `point.y` the tooltip doesn`t readjust when zooming, so if you zoom in the middle of the graph the graph should always start at 0, but the tooltip is showing yaxis value from when the graph wasn´t zoomed.

If I choose to show `point.change` it will readjust when zoom, but the total shows wrong. For example should the last point (2017-12-28) show 320.59%, and when using `point.change` its showing 318.78% (which is wrong).

How can I fix so the tooltip pointformat readjusts when zooming? I'm using `compare: 'value'` in `plotOptions {}` so the graph starts at 0 when zooming.

Please see fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cabvvpze/2/

Comment: `point.change` seems to have the incorrect value because the compare function does not like the first value `0`. This shifts all values by the difference of the first and second point, i.e. `1.8`. I tried setting the first point to 0.00001 and that does seem to give `point.change` the correct value. Not posting this as an answer since it not really a solution. See http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/cabvvpze/3/ for my example.

Comment: Well it might be an work around worth trying, and then keep looking for a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `point.change` is calculated using the first `non-null` and `non-zero` value (https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.compare). When the chart is not zoomed the first value that satisfies this condition is ~1.81 (second point) - everything is done using this value as baseline.

Series hold the information about this specific value in `compareValue` property - it can be used in `tooltip.pointFormatter` to achieve the desired result.

If the chart is not zoomed (it can be determined by checking whether `chart.resetZoomButton` is initialized or not) print `series.compareValue + point.change` in the tooltip. Otherwise use `point.change`.

```
  pointFormatter: function() {
    var series = this.series,
      chart = series.chart;

    return '<span style="color:{' + series.color + '}"></span>' + ((!chart.resetZoomButton ? series.compareValue : 0) + this.change) + '%<br/>';

  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/32kuokhb/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Is that the desired final result?: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/32kuokhb/

Comment: Yes! That is correct! Thanks! Update your answer and I will accept it